# TFS 2015 Build: Test results not being published

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, mstest, tfs-2015

I'm having a really weird error when TFS 2015 executes an automated test step.

The results are generated, but it seems TFS unable to find them.

In the end, it just says that no results were found to publish (which is weird, because it even outputs the result full path)

Check below the build logs for more info:

```
2015-12-16T15:44:29.5816976Z Executing the powershell script: C:\TfsBuildAgents\VsoBuildAgent\tasks\VSTest\1.0.22\VSTest.ps1

2015-12-16T15:44:29.7066995Z ##[debug]Calling Invoke-VSTest for all test assemblies

2015-12-16T15:44:30.4723241Z Working folder: C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1

2015-12-16T15:44:30.4723241Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\Rx.Api.V2.Tests\bin\Rx.Api.V2.Tests.dll"  /Settings:"C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\Staging.runsettings" /EnableCodeCoverage /inIsolation /logger:trx

2015-12-16T15:44:30.7379639Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.24720.0

2015-12-16T15:44:30.7379639Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

2015-12-16T15:44:30.9567007Z Starting test execution, please wait...

2015-12-16T15:44:38.2067012Z Passed   Login

2015-12-16T15:44:39.6129523Z Passed   GetMyEndpoints

2015-12-16T15:44:39.6129523Z Passed   GetEndpoint

2015-12-16T15:44:42.3648007Z Passed   Impersonate

2015-12-16T15:45:23.0904977Z Passed   SingleHotel_BookTwoPaxesOnSingleRoom

2015-12-16T15:45:50.8053379Z Passed   SingleHotel_BookOnePaxOnSingleRoom

2015-12-16T15:46:20.5444670Z Passed   SingleHotel_BookFourPaxesOnTwoRooms

2015-12-16T15:46:53.4013344Z Passed   SingleHotel_BookFourPaxesOnFourRooms

2015-12-16T15:47:03.3137055Z Passed   Location_BookOnePaxOnOneRoom

2015-12-16T15:47:03.5168256Z Results File: C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\TestResults\LOCAL SERVICE_YODA 2015-12-16 15_44_38.trx

2015-12-16T15:47:03.5168256Z Attachments:

2015-12-16T15:47:03.5324554Z   C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\TestResults\46904440-50c9-4522-b3c8-a84356b83b27\LOCAL SERVICE_YODA 2015-12-16 15_44_33.coverage

2015-12-16T15:47:03.5324554Z Total tests: 9. Passed: 9. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.

2015-12-16T15:47:03.5324554Z Test Run Successful.

2015-12-16T15:47:03.5324554Z Test execution time: 2.4823 Minutes

2015-12-16T15:47:03.6887046Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
```

Comment: Are you using the "publish test results" task?

Comment: That's correct! The native step called "Visual Studio Test" from the "Test" category in that list

Comment: So far, I've determined that having a Run Settings File is what causes this issue.

Comment: Hey @HighFiveBoom, you gave me some good clarity into this problem, because I've just realized that .runsettings actually dictates where the tests results are gonna be outputed, therefore, it should match the TFS directory, which is two levels above, so I'm guessing by changing the <ResultsDirectory> value from .\TestsResults to ..\TestsResults should do the trick,

I'll let you know tomorrow at the office, thanks again for the insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your runsettings file, comment out the ResultsDirectory tag under the RunConfiguration section.