# TFS Build 2015 No results found to publish

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

When using the new TFS Build 2015 vNext, the test ran but the result is not published. The tests run fine locally with results. Any help would be great.

```
Executing the powershell script:
C:\users\x\downloads\agent\tasks\VSTest\1.0.32\VSTest.ps1
Working folder: C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1
Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\x.Tests\bin\Debug\x.Tests.dll"  /logger:trx
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Starting test execution, please wait...
Information: Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true
No results found to publish
```

[See image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4U8k.png)
This is using the new build vNext. Can't find the problem anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What test framework are you using? Is it successfully running the tests?

Comment: Visual Studio Test. Yes, I can open and run on Visual Studio without problems.

Comment: Here is the full log downloaded from TFS: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqjGqhvxupemodhxpg6XVEZsmJKA3g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to install on your build server the last updates of Visual Studio, and Sql Server Data Tools.

Comment: Build Server has the latest update 3 of Visual Studio and SQL Server Data Tools. TFS is TFS 2015 Update 3, latest.

Comment: I just checked and it seems to be working fine now. Could be due to TFS Build doesn't have an updated version of Visual Studio or the component not fully installed.

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, there is no test result generated. You need to check whether `C:\TfsData\Build\_work\1\s\TKSLibrary.Tests\bin\Debug\TKSLibrary.Tests.dll` is the correct path and `TKSLibrary.Tests.dll` is the correct file that you want to run.

Meanwhile, try to use vstest.console.exe command line directly on your build agent machine to run the test, and check whether you can get the test result.

A similar case here for your reference: [TFS 2015 Build: Test results not being published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316717/tfs-2015-build-test-results-not-being-published), maybe it can help you find out the issue.

Comment: Yes, this is the dll I expect the test results. I just tried running it manually as you suggested, no issues. Here is the result [link](http://i.imgur.com/9NOzD8k.png?1)

Comment: There is no ResultsDirectory in the runsettings file. Here is the runsettings file. It's a default one. [link](http://i.imgur.com/21ta89B.png?1)